# How to create laravel passport refresh token

Tags: oauth-2.0, laravel-9, laravel-passport, refresh-token

How to create refreshingtoken using laravel passport.I create access token when login `$user->createToken('Laravel')->accessToken`.After login Refreshingtoken not working how to create

Answer (score 0):

If your application issues short-lived access tokens, users will need to refresh their access tokens via the refresh token that was provided to them when the access token was issued:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
 
$response = Http::asForm()->post('http://YOURSITE.COM/oauth/token', [
    'grant_type' => 'refresh_token',
    'refresh_token' => 'the-refresh-token',
    'client_id' => 'client-id',
    'client_secret' => 'client-secret',
    'scope' => '',
]);
 
return $response->json();
```

This `/oauth/token` route will return a JSON response containing `access_token`, `refresh_token`, and `expires_in` attributes. The `expires_in` attribute contains the number of seconds until the access token expires.

**Taken from:** https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport#refreshing-tokens

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth/token its not working please explain with example

Comment: explain what is not working, what error are you getting?

Comment: In postman the request send continuously and get error given below "message": "cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 30001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth/token",post('http://127.0.0.1:8001/oauth/token', [
            'grant_type' => 'refresh_token',
            'refresh_token' => '',
            'client_id' => '6394563ecadc4a29ad0d78a2',
            'client_secret' => 'EqujoLQIcjn3KgDaZU3NevKScaMXDGiwF0PWmng5',
            'scope' => '',

Comment: Are you calling the oauth/token directly?? you are supposed to create an api route with the code above, and let the code above call the oauth/token!

Comment: Yes i call the route directly after login i will call this route.in login i have get an access token then i call refreshtoken in postman.below code Route::get('refresh-token', [userController::class, 'refreshtoken']);  $response = Http::asForm()->post('http://127.0.0.1:8001/oauth/token', [
            'grant_type' => 'refresh_token',
            'refresh_token' => 'the-refresh-token',
            'client_id' => '6394563ecadc4a29ad0d78a2',
            'client_secret' => 'EqujoLQIcjn3KgDaZU3NevKScaMXDGiwF0PWmng5',
            'scope' => '',
        ]);
        return $response->json();

Comment: http://YOURSITE.COM/oauth/token here i try http://127.0.0.1:8001/oauth/token response error showing.

Comment: The answer is wrong. It doesn't explain how to get the refresh token at the first place